# J-Link script to flash program in S32K144 (allow security)

Tags: microcontroller, cortex-m, nxp-microcontroller, segger-jlink

I want to secure S32K144 using J-Link script but not able to program the security bits and hence verification failed.
So how to specify device **S32K144 (allow security)** in J-Link script?

I have specified device S32K144 in J-Link script. I have use code in which security bits were enabled.

> "C:\Program Files\SEGGER\JLink\JLink.exe" -speed 4000 -if SWD -device S32K144 -CommanderScript Debug.Command

I'm getting message as below:

> Verify failed @ address 0x0000040C.
> Expected BF read BE.

I want to program S32K144 using J-Link script. Is it possible to program security bits with J-Link script? If yes then how to select device **S32K144 (allow security)**?

Comment: What did segger say when you asked?  What did NXP say when you asked?  What debug did you do?  Did you do more than run the one command?

Comment: Did not got any response from segger. Using Debug.Command in which downloading application into flash as follows: erase, loadbin File.bin,0x00000000,  verifybin File.bin,0x00000000